# How to model a complex shape like this ornate window?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm stumped. Two hours now and I can't get it to work. How would you make this window? You are a godsend if you can help. (see the little red circle on the image)

I can create the outer part of it, but unlike a square window which I have no issues with (extruding in, deleting faces, etc), I can't figure this one out.

[image]

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A larger image would be helpful.

Comment: For future reference this is called a transom window.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are **many** possible ways you could go about it, but perhaps this will give you some ideas.

Instead of thinking of the window as a solid chunk, think about the separate parts (sill, frame, bar things, glass, etc.) as, well, separate.

For example:

1. Model the frame:

   [image]
2. Add the bar things as separate parts:

   [image]
3. Add the glass:

   [image]

*The result here is admittedly pretty terrible, but in my defense I was hurrying so that the the gifs wouldn't be too big.. If you spend a little more time adding details to each of the components, you can get something more like this:*

[image]

By adding even more detail (e.g. screws) to the places were parts are attached, you might make it even more believable.

Comment: Perfect -- exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you look at your vertices, the lines are going perpendicularly to the spokes on the window. What you want is to add a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Mesh > Circle)
[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > At Center.
Delete half (edit mode <kbd>B</kbd> select half, <kbd>Delete</kbd> > Delete Vertices)

Scale as desired.

And add a wireframe modifier (Modifiers > Add Modifier > Wireframe).
[image]

You should get something like this, which can then be edited to fit your specific needs.
[image]

NOTICE: The initial subdivision of the circle will directly affect the resulting number of spokes!

Comment: This is a great answer, but it makes some unnecessary geometry for my purposes here. This answer really does give me a different perspective regarding the initial ordering of vertices in my starting primitives, plus this cool technique. Thanks!